# Database normalization question

Tags: sql, database, database-design, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I just started learning about database normalization and I have a question about one of my tables. My database right now is structured horribly, and one of the reasons is because I have a table that looks like this.

**Customers Table**

```
ID |  Date_Entered   |  First_Name  |  Middle_Name |  Last_Name |    Maiden_Name
```

...

```
Address__street_dmv | Address_city_dmv  | Address_state_dmv |   Address_zip_dmv
```

...

```
Address__street_source2  |  Address_state_source2  |  Address_city_source2  | etc
```

.

The addresses keeping going on and on because my company obtains address data from multiple sources. But, of course, some of these address will be Null for some of our customers. So I think I need a separate addresses table like this that connects to the Customers table.

.

**Addresses**

```
ID  |   Number  |    Street    |  State  |   Zip  |    Source (drop down menu)
```

But then I was thinking the source would be redundant data. So, do I need a separate sources table like this?

**Sources**

```
Source_ID  |    Source
```

And change the addresses table like this?

```
ID  |   Number    |  Street    |  State  |   Zip    |  Source _ID (drop down)
```

It doesn’t seem right because now the Source_ID is redundant… Please help.

Bonus points if you can tell me whether or not I should include Maiden and Middle names in the Customer table since these too could possibly be Null (If not, how would the new table be structured?)

Sorry for being a noob.

Comment: Hey, you're on the right track, don't feel bad.  We're here to help (especially nicely worded, specific questions like this).  Although I think, from the stuff I keep hearing about Access, that some people would recommend a different database product... (never used it myself, so can't really say).

Comment: Database normalization is designed to make your data more reliable, easier to use, and your structure easier to understand.  You should absolutely normalize your data to achieve those three goals.  However, it's very possible to over-normalize a database.  If creating another table for a piece of info isn't necessary for reliability's sake and just forces another join in your common queries then don't do it.  Maiden/middle names are one of those situations where it's fine to just leave it in your main table.

Comment: You need to duplicate a field like Source_ID so it will allow you to join the records of two different tables. This is the exeption to duplicating data, it's how relational databases work.

Comment: @X-Zero - when someone is learning how to cut down a tree with a hand saw, hold off on recommending a chainsaw until they grasp the basics. Access is just fine for many applications. Most people who are discouraged by Access have not used the improved latest versions.

Comment: When you are normalizing your database design, you have to remember that foreign keys "don't count" when you are considering redundancy.  However, this is only true if your foreign keys are meaningless.  In your example, Source_ID is good because it is just a number that no user will ever see directly.  Using a meaningful value here, like "DMV" is dangerous because it is visible to users and is therefore at risk of being changed.  For example, DMV might be renamed to "Vehicle Ministry".  If you use your Source_ID design this will be one simple edit.  If not it will be a big mess!

Comment: @X-Zero: denormalization is possible in every database engine. There's not something specific to Access that causes people to create spreadsheet data tables instead -- it's usually a case where people just don't know enough about database design. I've seen enough horrid website databases to know that this problem is not by any means restricted to Access users...

Comment: @Joel, Foreign keys *do* count! Normalization is about eliminating redundancy due to non-key dependencies. Normalization doesn't care whether any attribute happens to be a foreign key or not. What matters are the dependencies that are supposed to be satisfied.

Comment: @dportas - OK, 600 characters wasn't enough room to be precise.  When I say "foreign keys don't count" I am talking about a common misperception that I have heard from many people who haven't yet grasped normalization.  They think, as did OP apparently, that because a key is repeated once in one table (as PK) and again in another table (as FK) that this means the key itself is redundant.  Look for yourself and see that OP says this about "Source_ID" fourth line from the bottom of his post.  This is what I was referring to.  Clearly you need to normalize your FKs just like any other attributes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go with something like

**Customer**

```
ID |  Date_Entered  |  First_Name  |  Middle_Name | Last_Name | Maiden_Name
```

**Addresses**

```
ID  |   Number  |    Street    |  State_ID  |   Zip
```

**Customers_Address**

```
ID | Customer_ID | Address_ID | Source_ID
```

This allows you to have same address from multiple sources. You might also want to have separate table for streets, possibly like

```
Table_Street (ID | State_ID | Name)
```

and then in the `Addresses` table you would only have `Street_ID` instead of both `Street` and `State_ID`. This also allows you to show a selection list of streets when user has selected state.

I'd say it is OK to have Maiden and Middle names in the Customer table, even if they are rarely used.

Comment: I'm with you on this one, although the OP may not need the multiple-source/multiple-customer address optimization (probably a good idea though).  `Maiden_Name` is potentially a different name for the same customer  (a previous name, that was a different last name), depending on use-case.

Answer (score 1):

Part of your question has to do with normalization, and part of it does not. That doesn't mean part of your question isn't important. It just means it's important for reasons that have nothing to do with normalization.

Your addresses are essentially a repeating group, in one sense of that term. So it does make sense to remove them from Customers. (This has to do with normalization; repeating groups violates 1NF.)

"Source" is not redundant data, and deciding whether to substitute an ID number for text has nothing to do with normalization.

When you move a table from a lower normal form to a higher normal form, the original table ends up with fewer columns. Substituting an ID number for text doesn't change the number of columns.

And every column in which you substitute a meaningless ID number for text requires a join to get the meaningful text back. Following your same logic, you could also substitute meaningless ID numbers for street, state, and zip, but that would then require four joins to get meaningful data back.

Comment: Thanks Catcall, that actually makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an SQL expert but here is what I think you are trying to describe.

A customer which is an unique entity has a current address and can have many other addresses, if this is correct yes you should separate the additional addresses into their own table.

Secondly the way you discover that a customer has x amount of addresses is that you obtain this information different companies for each customer, if this is the case I would have a separate table for the companies and record this as you planned, yes you will have repeating rows of source_id but this would be the case as they supply information about many different customers.

In relation to the maiden and middle names are these required by your business rules if so store them when required.

Again my SQL development is only student level really but from what I understand this is how I would go about it.

Hope this helps and if anyone can give more expert information go with it.

Answer (score 0):

you could also try the following approach:

**Customer**

> CustomerID (PK) |  Date_Entered  |  First_Name  |  Middle_Name | Last_Name |
>   Maiden_Name

**Addresses**

> CustomerId (PK)(FK) | SourceID(PK) | Number | Street | State| Zip

This assumes a one-to-many relationship between Customer and Addresses.  It also eliminates the Customer_Address table altogether, in favor of using two tables (Customer and Addresses), and defining a compound primary key for the Addresses table as the CustomerId and the SourceID.  In this model, the CustomerId and the SourceId uniquely determines the Number, Street, State, and Zip.  It also enforces data integrity by ensuring that each customer can only have one address from each source.  Let me know if this helps or if I'm way off base.  I'm still learning!